# Find a file when you know its checksum?

Tags: find, aix, hashsum

I have the `md5sum` of a file and I don't know where it is on my system.  Is there any easy option of `find` to identify a file based on its `md5`? Or do I need to develop a small script ?

I'm working on AIX 6 without the GNU tools.

Comment: Wouldn't narrowing the search to file sizes of the same size then computing the md5 be faster?

Comment: @RJ- yes maybe but in this case it also allow me to check if the file is the correct one and has been transfer correctly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find /tmp/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep '^file_md5sum_to_match'
```

If you searching through `/` then you can exclude `/proc` and `/sys` see following `find` command example :

Also I had done some testing, `find` take more time and less CPU and RAM where ruby script is taking less time but more CPU and RAM

**Test Result**

**Find**

```
[root@dc1 ~]# time find / -type f -not -path "/proc/*" -not -path "/sys/*" -exec md5sum {} + | grep '^304a5fa2727ff9e6e101696a16cb0fc5'
304a5fa2727ff9e6e101696a16cb0fc5  /tmp/file1


real    6m20.113s
user    0m5.469s
sys     0m24.964s
```

**Find with `-prune`**

```
[root@dc1 ~]# time find / \( -path /proc -o -path /sys \) -prune -o -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep '^304a5fa2727ff9e6e101696a16cb0fc5'
304a5fa2727ff9e6e101696a16cb0fc5  /tmp/file1

real    6m45.539s
user    0m5.758s
sys     0m25.107s
```

**Ruby Script**

```
[root@dc1 ~]# time ruby findm.rb
File Found at: /tmp/file1

real    1m3.065s
user    0m2.231s
sys     0m20.706s
```

Comment: You want to call `-prune` on `/sys`/`/proc` instead of descending in them and exclude files with `-path`. You should prefer `!` over `-not` for portability.

Comment: Sir I've updated with -prune, once check if it is OK.

Comment: You also want to exclude `/dev` certainly.

Answer (score 12):

**Script Solution**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'find'
require 'digest/md5'

file_md5sum_to_match = [ '304a5fa2727ff9e6e101696a16cb0fc5',
                         '0ce6742445e7f4eae3d32b35159af982' ]

Find.find('/') do |f|
  next if /(^\.|^\/proc|^\/sys)/.match(f) # skip
  next unless File.file?(f)
  begin
        md5sum = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read(f))
  rescue
        puts "Error reading #{f} --- MD5 hash not computed."
  end
  if file_md5sum_to_match.include?(md5sum)
       puts "File Found at: #{f}"
       file_md5sum_to_match.delete(md5sum)
  end
  file_md5sum_to_match.empty? && exit # if array empty then exit

end
```

**Bash Script solution based on probability which works faster**

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -z $1 ]] && read -p "Enter MD5SUM to search file: " md5 || md5=$1

check_in=( '/home' '/opt' '/tmp' '/etc' '/var' '/usr'  )
last_find_cmd="find / \\( -path /proc -o -path /sys ${check_in[@]/\//-o -path /} \\) -prune -o -type f -exec md5sum {} +"
last_element=${#check_in}
echo "Please wait... searching for file"
for d in ${!check_in[@]}
do

        [[ $d == $last_element ]] && eval $last_find_cmd | grep "^${md5}" && exit

        find ${check_in[$d]} -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep "^${md5}" && exit


done
```

**Test Result**

```
[root@dc1 /]# time bash find.sh 304a5fa2727ff9e6e101696a16cb0fc5
Please wait... searching for file
304a5fa2727ff9e6e101696a16cb0fc5  /var/log/file1

real    0m21.067s
user    0m1.947s
sys     0m2.594s
```

Comment: which would you recommend ?

Comment: @Kiwy I'm not recommend, Just for practice

Comment: @Kiwy once look at test result and let me know and also do some testing from your side and show us the result, It would be great to see result on AIX. :D

Comment: My main issue with your script is that it needs ruby and it's not install on my System, and I'm not admin. but I will run some test tonight if I find some time

Comment: It seems faster than find in the end ^^. maybe you could put the md5sum  in a thread so you can compute 5 md5sum at the same time it could save also a bit of time

Comment: @Kiwy I've updated the code, now you can many md5 hashes as you want

Answer (score 8):

If you decide to install gnu find anyway (and since you indicated interest in one of your comments), you can try something like:

```
find / -type f \( -exec checkmd5 {} YOURMD5SUM \; -o -quit \)
```

and have `checkmd5` compare the md5sum of the file it gets as argument compare to
the second argument and print the name if it matches and exit with 1 (instead of 0 otherwise). The `-quit` will  have `find` stop once it is found.

`checkmd5` (not tested):

```
#!/bin/bash

md=$(md5sum $1 |  cut -d' ' -f1)

if [ $md == $2 ] ; then
  echo $1
  exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Yum `No package checkmd5 available`, please include which package need to be install for `checkmd5`

Comment: I like this solution too bad I don't get `checkmd5` but I like the way you do it

Comment: @kiwy script added.

Comment: @RahulPatil it is in the DIY distribution ;-)

Comment: @kiwy Sorry could have accepted your edit for `-type f`, but it undeleted my `echo $1` I already had put in

Answer (score 1):

For people running macOS and stumbling on this page: you have to use `md5` instead of `md5sum` or `checkmd5`, i.e.:

```
find . -type f -exec md5 {} + | grep  'file_md5sum_to_match'
```

Caveat: also don't put `^` before `file_md5sum_to_match` otherwise it will never match anything since `md5` prints the filename before its md5 sum.